# How to stop icing from running off iced buns?

Tags: baking, icing

Recently I've attempted to make iced buns and as a first attempt, they went well. However, after one night my icing began to slide off the top of the buns, leaving me with either bare or patch-worked buns and a pool of dried icing. Can anyone tell me why it happens and/or how to stop it?

Comment: Were the buns floury on top before you iced them? Also, what icing recipe are you using?

Comment: ... piling on, were the buns warm (versus fully cooled) when you iced them?  Was it warm or humid in your kitchen? Did you keep them in the refrigerator or "out"? Heat and humidity can be fatal...

Answer (score 2):

I think you can find your answer [here](http://www.craftsy.com/blog/2013/06/hot-weather-cake-decoration/). Basically, when the ambient temperature of the surroundings is on the higher side, the icing melts since the butter cannot remain in a solid state. However, what can be done according to the link that I posted, you can add 2 tablespoons of cornstarch per 3 cups of icing to make the icing sturdier. Or you can use other ingredients like gelatin, or meringue powder which does the same as well.